# Easiest way to recreate the iPhone SMS application's user interface?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, user-interface, sms

Greetings!

as a beginner in iPhone application development using Objective-C, I was wondering what was the easiest way to recreate the iPhone SMS app's UI (the one with message bubbles and such)

I've thought of using a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell that uses images to recreate the message bubbles. this works fine when the message thread contains only a small number of messages, but once it exceeds a certain amount, there is significant amount of time from when the view is pushed to a UINavigationController until it actually displays on screen. I believe that this is caused by computing for the height of each table cell (as well as the message bubbles).

I know that a lot of other chat clients have implemented user interfaces like such, but I can't seem to find a proper tutorial on how to do so.

links to tutorials or frameworks will be greatly appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right track. I think the best option is a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCell` instances as cells.

Make sure you are using a cell caching technique to avoid creating one cell for each different message you are trying to show. That might be slowing you down.

Check out [this](http://www.cocoacast.com/cocoacast/?q=node/182) (dead) tutorial. It's great for what you want, and it will explain you how to reuse your cell components.

Comment: Also, atebits has a great writeup on how to improve scrolling performance on the iPhone. http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/

Comment: thanks guys! I'm far far away from my workstation so I'll have to wait til Monday before I check these out. Pablo's link was surely helpful since I realized that I haven't really been using cell caching in any of my UITableViews

Answer (score 0):

A helpful framework for most iOS apps is [Three20](http://three20.info/).  The documentation is a little scarce, but there is a ton of stuff in there.  I thought of this framework for your app specifically because of the [TTSpeechBubbleShape](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_speech_bubble_shape.php) class designed to imitate the SMS speech bubbles exactly.

This framework is being actively worked on and is the framework behind the Facebook app and literally hundreds more.  It is designed to be powerful, perform well, and to make your life easier.

More information on the huge amount of classes that are available to you can be found here:
http://api.three20.info/annotated.php

Comment: isn't Three20 a little bit too much overkill if say I would just use it for the TTSpeechBubble? I already heard of this framework while search for a means copying SMS app's compose message interface, but upon reading up on how to use Three20, it seemed like adding too many dependencies to my project just to use a single object was just way too much for me. please correct me if I'm wrong though

Comment: If that's all you use it for you're probably right. But there are a lot of really good and useful things in there and I end up using it in most of my apps. There are replacements for standard classes (such as UITableView) that make things much easier.  Bottom line: if it's going to take you 3 hours to make a good looking and well performing speech bubble vs 15 minutes to hook up the dependencies, overkill may become subjective.  You're call. Just wanted you to be aware of this tool.  Good luck with your project. :)